# Open Graph title and description are ignored by LinkedIn but the Image is correctly shared

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I have trouble sharing page URLs from the website http://www.waterlinedata.com/ on LinkedIn: the Open Graph title and Description are ignored .However, the Facebook Debug tool returns all the information correctly (so I assumed the og tags are correct)

ex: www.waterlinedata.com/careers/

With the FB Debug, the `og:title` (     Careers | Waterline Data is hiring ) is correctly returned. However when trying to share the same link on LinkedIn, the `og:title` is ignored and it seems that the last part of the URL 'careers' is displayed instead.

Here is a screenshot from Facebook Debug [image: Facebook Debug - Correct og:title]

And below is a screenshot of a share on LinkedIn :

[image: Share on LinkedIn]

AS you can notice the `og:title` is not displayed (instead is the word "career" which is the name of the WordPress page and the last part of the URL ...)

It is a WordPress website, running the SEO plugin by Yoast.

Could someone help me resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

LinkedIn provides the two following modes for the sharing API preview...

- **Level 1**

  - *You supply:* `og:image` tags.
  - *Preview shows:* title, url, image.
- **Level 2**

  - *You supply:* no `og:image` tags, but an `og:description` tag.
  - *Preview shows:* title, url, description.

Regardless of the applicable level, the `og:` tags for title and url always display fine.

Since you supply an image, the description will not display.  The **[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Sharing Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**, which mentions the four tags (title, url, description, image), is silent on this matter.

We can test it, though.  Wikipedia has no image tag, but a description tag, and we only see the description when [sharing Wikipedia](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F).  GitHub, on the other hand, has both image and description tags, and we only see the image when [sharing GitHub](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F).

A conversation with LinkedIn support over the course of two weeks yielded no result. (*[oh the humanity](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html)*)  So, I think we are stuck with just the image for now in the LinkedIn preview.  Right now, it seems like nobody can fix this but Microsoft themselves.